# Apache httpd: Conditionally set response header based on other *response* header

Tags: apache, apache2

Is there a way to set a new response header conditionally, where the condition uses another **response** header? Specifically, the new response header should be set only if the response has a certain Content-Type.

I have looked into [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) in combination with [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) but it looks like conditions can only use **request** headers, not response headers.

Thanks, John

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but for now I'm stuck with apache-2.2. A sollution for that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apache 2.4 is the answer:

Set Cache-Control header when response content type is application/pdf

`Header set Cache-Control "no-store,no-transform" "expr=%{resp:Content-Type} =~ m|application/pdf|"`

Do NOT try with the IF directive.  It is evaluated too early in the process. For example, the following will NOT work:

`<If "%{resp:Content-Type} =~ m|application/pdf|">
       Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-transform"
</If>`

Comment: The documentation for mod_headers state that `expr=value available in 2.4.10 and later`. Is there another way to do this on Apache <= 2.4.6?