# Apache-2.2 Set-Cookie on logic from a response header

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I need to set a cookie based on a *response header* (as opposed to a request header). The response header is set by a SOAP call to a backend - and is out of apaches control.

I've looked into SetEnvIf, but it states that it investigate request headers only. mod_rewrite's {HTTP:parm} construct also seems to apply to request headers only.

1. Request coming in
2. Response header is generated by backend
3. Apache investigates respond header FooBar
4. Apache add Set-Cookie if the respond header FooBar value matches "string"

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like this can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27747860/2493235) with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header), but unfortunately only with Apache 2.4, since expressions were only added in 2.4. You would do something like:

```
Header set Set-Cookie "cookie-contents-here" "expr=%{resp:Content-Type} =~ m|application/pdf|"
```

If you can't upgrade to 2.4, you might consider putting Varnish Cache in front of your Apache install. It's a powerful HTTP processor and can easily handle modifying the response for you. You could also implement caching with it and increase the performance of your site, but it can just be used as a pass-through HTTP processor if you don't want to do that. Perhaps there's a simpler solution but that would work.

Another option could be to put a layer in between Apache and your back-end, such as a PHP script, that handles passing the call to the back-end and modifying the headers on the way back out. Probably not great for performance though; upgrading Apache or implementing Varnish Cache would be better.

If you're using a separate back-end out of Apache's control, then you might take Apache out of the loop completely and go straight from Varnish Cache to your back-end.

Hope the ideas help.

Comment: We're stuck with apache-2.2 for now. It's bundled in IBM HTTP Server 8 which still is at 2.2. I'm considering IHS 9 which _has_ apache-2.4 but on a production server that will take some time. Thanks for your response :-)